# How can I change which shell script mode I'm in?

Tags: major-mode, commands, shell-mode

Occasionally, emacs opens a file in `shell-script[fish]` when I want it to open in `shell-script[bash]`. How can I manually change the subtype of shell-script mode that I'm in?

Comment: When a file opens in `shell-script[fish]`, what extension does it have? Can you provide any more details about what leads up to this behaviour? Also, what is the value for `sh-shell-file` when you do `C-h v sh-shell-file RET`? (I deleted my previous comment and am reposting it because it had a major typo but it was too late to edit it)

Comment: @elethan: There is no file extension. I'm ok with it opening in fish mode, I just want to know how to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is determining whether you see `shell-script[fish]` or `shell-script[bash]` is probably:

1. The extension of the file (`*.sh` files will probably open with `shell-script[bash]`, and `*.fish` files will probably open with `shell-script[fish]`)
2. The starting #!-line (e.g., if the first line of the file you are opening is `#!/bin/bash`, it should start in `shell-script[bash]`).

I am not sure in your case what is causing your files to open in different submodes (if you provide further detail in your question I will update my answer if necessary), but if you want to be able to manually switch between submodes as you say, you can do so with the command `M-x sh-set-shell` (for me it is bound to `C-c :`) and then select your desired shell from a list of completions or type it in yourself. It should also update the #!-line of whatever script you are editing.

Comment: One small problem, mentioned already in this answer, is that `sh-set-shell` (when used interactively) inserts a shebang and makes the file executable. This might be undesirable for files which are meant to be `source`d, not executed, by other scripts as so-called "shell libraries".